# What is the correct technique to press single notes with left hand

Tags: piano

What is the technique when it comes to pressing single notes with the left hand? (See piano sheets)
In this case should I move my left hamd fingers as if I were playing a fast arpeggio (chicken schratcing), or should I use the weight and gravity of my hand for each note?

Often times when I play single notes with the left hand, it sounds like they are not the same length.

[image]

Comment: One reason why arpeggios need lots of practice is for performing pieces such as this. Pedalling will smooth it out, as the stretch is often too much to play it smoothly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left hand in this example of piano music should be played with damper pedal held for each chord's duration, typically beats 1 and 2 and then again during beats 3 and 4.  Therefore, "note length" isn't a concern.

Think of the left hand's physical motion as aiming the fingers at the keys, then rolling the wrist to strike each key with about the same force.  Try emphasizing the arpeggio's bottom note.

Even if the arpeggio is "bigger than your hand", think of it the same way - either by playing one of the middle notes with the thumb and moving the hand over, or with one big stretch as in some of Chopin's etudes.